# Update value in oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a database table `Land` with colums:

`serial, seller_name, sell_date, sell_price`

I am using a datablock named `land`. To update the table I am using the same datablocks field. I am using a lov to take the already saved values and I am dropping those values in the datablock `land`.

I want to update the values based on the serial number. I am using on `button pressed trigger` under a button and used the `commit_form`. But every time new data is inserted with the same serial number. I am looking for a way to update the table for that specific serial number.

Comment: What do you mean with serial number? How do you generate it? How do you set it to the data?

Answer (score 0):

To load the right row into the data block, you have to do the following in your trigger:

```
 enter_query(no_validate);
 :serial := your_lov.whatever;
 execute_query;
```

This will connect the datablock with the correct row, instead of overwriting another row.